# Why am I getting IllegalMonitorStateException with this code?

Tags: java

I have 2 threads, one calls get() method, another put() method.
I need to synchronize this methods in order to see result of get only after put. I do know how to do this other way, but I want to understand why am i getting .IllegalMonitorStateException with this code.

```
public class TransferObject {

    private int value;
    protected volatile boolean isValuePresent = false; //use this variable

    public synchronized int get() {
        synchronized (TransferObject.class) {

            System.out.println("Got: " + value);
            notify();
        }
        return value;
    }


    public void put(int value) {

        synchronized (TransferObject.class) {
            this.value = value;
            System.out.println("Put: " + value);
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is example of 2 threads.

```
public class ConsumerTask implements Runnable {
    private TransferObject transferObject;
    protected volatile boolean stopped;

    public ConsumerTask(TransferObject transferObject) {
        this.transferObject = transferObject;
        new Thread(this, "ConsumerTask").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!stopped) {
            transferObject.get();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopped = true;
    }
}


public class ProducerTask implements Runnable {

    private TransferObject transferObject;
    protected volatile boolean stopped;
    static volatile AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public ProducerTask(TransferObject transferObject) {
        this.transferObject = transferObject;
        new Thread(this, "ProducerTask").start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!stopped) {
            transferObject.put(i.incrementAndGet());
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        stopped = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because you assumed that `ProducerTask` will run first. What will happen if the `ConsumerTask` run first?

Comment: You lock on `TransferObject.class` but then call `wait()`/`notify()` on `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two threads and one object for locking `TransferObject.class`.
When your thread ConsumerTask gets the lock, object `TransferObject.class` don't have sleeping threads, and when you call notify() for this monitor you get `IllegalMonitorStateException`

From the description for method notify:

```
Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.
```

You don't have waiting treads for monitor `TransferObject.class`